# Subqueries in the 'Select' or 'Order by' are not supported if the subquery is not part of the 'Group by'

Tags: sql, vertica

new to SQL, I am trying to use subquery to come up with a 'running %' of a column but getting an error seen in the title.

My table structure looks like:

```
col_name, value1
a           6
b           5
c           4
d           3
e           2
f           1
```

I need to add the % Total & cumulative % of so it will look like:

```
col_name, value1, % Total  , cumulative %
a           6        28.5%     28.5%
b           5        23.8%     52.3%
c           4        19.04%    71.2%
d           3        14.28%    84.5%
e           2         9.5%     94%  
f           1         4.7%     100%
```

could you please advice how to go about it using subquery?

Tried the following code on another table:

```
select a, sum(b), 
(select sum(b) from t1 where a <= t1.a) as running_total
from
t1 
group by 1
order by 3
```

I need to add the % Total & cumulative % of so it will look like:

```
col_name, value1, % Total  , cumulative %
a           6        28.5%     28.5%
b           5        23.8%     52.3%
c           4        19.04%    71.2%
d           3        14.28%    84.5%
e           2         9.5%     94%  
f           1         4.7%     100%
```

could you please advice how to go about it using subquery?

Comment: You are trying to get group values without changing the granularity of your query. Therefore, the database returns an error under these circunstances. To do so, you must use analytic functions which allows you to get that data with a different granularity level (in the case that your database engine supports them... I haven't ever worked with vertica)

Answer (score 2):

Use window functions!

```
select a, sum(b),
       sum(b) / sum(sum(b)) over () as ratio,
       sum(sum(b)) over (order by sum(b) desc) / sum(sum(b)) over () as running_ratio
from t1 
group by a
order by 3
```

Answer (score 0):

@Gordon - this is probably a first, in which I can't get your code to work - so I try to place my solution - and I can't seem to avoid a nested query - as you, @WUB, were already guessing.

Using exactly your input data in an initial WITH clause ...

```
WITH
-- this is your input, start your "real" WITH clause later
input(col_name,value1) AS (
          SELECT 'a',6
UNION ALL SELECT 'b',5
UNION ALL SELECT 'c',4
UNION ALL SELECT 'd',3
UNION ALL SELECT 'e',2
UNION ALL SELECT 'f',1
)
-- end of your input, start "real" WITH clause after this, with 
-- "WITH" instead of comma on the next line
,
input_w_rtr AS (
SELECT
  col_name
, value1
, (value1 * 100 / SUM(value1) OVER())::NUMERIC(4,2) AS ratio_to_report
FROM input
)
SELECT
  col_name
, value1
, ratio_to_report
, SUM(ratio_to_report) OVER(ORDER BY col_name) AS running_ratio_to_report
FROM input_w_rtr;
-- out  col_name | value1 | ratio_to_report | running_ratio_to_report 
-- out ----------+--------+-----------------+-------------------------
-- out  a        |      6 |           28.57 |                   28.57
-- out  b        |      5 |           23.81 |                   52.38
-- out  c        |      4 |           19.05 |                   71.43
-- out  d        |      3 |           14.29 |                   85.72
-- out  e        |      2 |            9.52 |                   95.24
-- out  f        |      1 |            4.76 |                  100.00
-- out (6 rows)
-- out 
-- out Time: First fetch (6 rows): 11.422 ms. All rows formatted: 11.465 ms
```